# how to use in statement in mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql-python

Seemed `mysqldb` has no abvious way to use `in` statement

```
execute('select * from test where id in(%s)','1,2,3')
```

will get `querysql="select * from test where id in ('1,2,3')"`

This aparently is not what I want. Now I have to use `execute` method many time and append `fetchall` result together.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data = [1,2,3]  # stores the data
in_part = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data))  # prepares formatting string
execute('select * from test where id in(' + in_part + ')', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list of numbers you can use this:

```
execute('select * from test where id in ({0},{1},{2})'.format(1, 2, 3))
# query 'select * from test where id in (1,2,3)'
```

if on the other hand you have a string use this:

```
execute('select * from test where id in ({0})'.format('1, 2, 3'))
# query 'select * from test where id in (1, 2, 3)'
```

In general use the `format()` function to manipulate with strings. Read more about it in official docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: I regret to inform you, but this is a bad idea. Are aware why there is a second parameter in `execute()`? See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/ Plus your solution does not support variable length sequences.

Comment: well,abviously format need actually the numbers to be filled,while thank u still

Comment: My mistake guys. Thanks Tadeck for pointing it out. I was just looking for string concatenation.